# Loop issue and odd code in my Python slot machine

Tags: python, loops, slot

i have already read all the other slot machine post, and i can understand the theory of the loop and get all the other solutions, until the code is simple and short.
my array is so bad at the moment that i can't really figure out why i can't play more than **one time**

here my entire array, it include the help came for other questions i have opened in the past 2 days.

please be sincere and rude if this code sucks:

```
import random
import time

cr = 100
print('[- play simple slot machine game -]')
time.sleep(1)
print('[- with five identical n you win -]')
time.sleep(1)
print('[- start at ' + str(cr) + 'cr place your bet -]')
time.sleep(1)
slot = []
for row in range(9):
    slot.append([None] * 9)


def print_slot(slot, empty='[ ]'):
    for row in slot:
        print(' '.join(empty if element is None else '{{: ^{}}}'.format(len(empty)).format(element) for element in row))

print_slot(slot)

time.sleep(1)
print('[- play simple slot machine game -]')
time.sleep(1)
print('[- with five identical n you win -]')
time.sleep(1)


def game_start():
    cr = 100
    bet = int(input('[- digit the num of coins to bet -] \n                 '))
    if (cr > 0) and (0 < bet <= cr):
        cr = 100 - bet
        first_n = random.randint(0, 9)
        second_n = random.randint(0, 9)
        third_n = random.randint(0, 9)
        fourth_n = random.randint(0, 9)
        fifth_n = random.randint(0, 9)
        slot[4][2] = str(first_n)
        slot[4][3] = str(second_n)
        slot[4][4] = str(third_n)
        slot[4][5] = str(fourth_n)
        slot[4][6] = str(fifth_n)

        if first_n == second_n and second_n == third_n and third_n == fourth_n and fourth_n == fifth_n:
            cr += bet * 100
            time.sleep(1)
            print('[- play simple slot machine game -]')
            time.sleep(1)
            print('[- with five identical n you win -]')
            time.sleep(1)
            print_slot(slot)
            time.sleep(1)
            print('[- with five identical n you win -]')
            time.sleep(1)
            print('[- you won!!! now you have ' + str(cr) + 'cr -]')
            bet = int(input('[- digit the num of coins to bet -] \n                 '))
            return bet

        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            print('[- play simple slot machine game -]')
            time.sleep(1)
            print('[- with five identical n you win -]')
            time.sleep(1)
            print_slot(slot)
            time.sleep(1)
            print('[- with five identical n you win -]')
            time.sleep(1)
            print('[- you loose! now you have  ' + str(cr) + 'cr -]')
            bet = int(input('[- digit the num of coins to bet -] \n                 '))
            return bet

    elif cr < 0:
        time.sleep(1)
        print('[- play simple slot machine game -]')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('[- with five identical n you win -]')
        time.sleep(1)
        print_slot(slot)
        time.sleep(1)
        print('[- with five identical n you win -]')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('[- you ran out of money 2 bet :( -]')

game_start()
```

Comment: already tried to put all under a loop `while cr > 0`
already tried to call `game_start` after returning `bet`

Comment: and yes i understand it's xmas right now, but the only thing i wanted yesterday and today was to complete this array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `-=` the credit each time there is a bet and just remove the elif, I removed some unnecessary lines, added a `try/except` to cast to an int and catch bad input and a way for the user to quit the game. You can add a sleep or two where you like but it should run how you want:

```
def game_start():
    cr = 100
    while cr > 0:
        bet = input('[- digit the num of coins to bet -] \n or enter q to quit')
        if bet == "q": # if user wants to quit they can enter q
            print("Thanks for playing, you are leaving with ${}".format(cr))
            return # leaves/ends the function
        try: # use try/except to cast to int to catch illegal input
           bet = int(bet)
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input")
            continue
        if bet <= cr: # make sure we have enough credit
            cr -= bet
            first_n = random.randint(0, 9)
            second_n = random.randint(0, 9)
            third_n = random.randint(0, 9)
            fourth_n = random.randint(0, 9)
            fifth_n = random.randint(0, 9)
            slot[4][2] = str(first_n)
            slot[4][3] = str(second_n)
            slot[4][4] = str(third_n)
            slot[4][5] = str(fourth_n)
            slot[4][6] = str(fifth_n)
        else: # if we get here we tried to bet too much so use continue to go back to start of loop and ask for bet again
            print("You don't have that much credit")
            continue
        # if we get here all is good 
        if len({first_n,second_n,third_n,fourth_n,fifth_n}) == 1: # sets don't have dups so if we have five that are equal we will only have one element
                cr += bet * 100
                time.sleep(1)
                print('[- play simple slot machine game -]')
                time.sleep(1)
                print('[- with five identical n you win -]')
                time.sleep(1)
                print_slot(slot)
                time.sleep(1)
                print('[- with five identical n you win -]')
                time.sleep(1)
                print('[- you won!!! now you have ' + str(cr) + 'cr -]')
        else: # if we did not have a winning spin we will get here
            print("Hard Luck, You have {} credit left".format(cr))
    # this will print if we run out of credit        
    print('[- you ran out of money 2 bet :( -]')
```

`cr = 100 - bet` keeps setting cr - equal to 100 - the current bet, it does not update the cr by decrementing by the bet amount.

Having a `return bet` in your code will cause the function to end when you reach that statement no matter how much credit you have, you only want to break/return when you have 0 dollars left or the user wants to leave.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point returning `bet`, since you don't do anything with the return value. Also, you can't do anything in the function *after* you return from it - it's like telling your kid to shut the door when he's already at the playground. Putting a loop in is the correct solution. Also, if you keep the constant `100` in the loop, it will never terminate unless the player inputs `100` or `0`. (Also, "loose" is opposite of "tight"; opposite of "win" is "lose".

```
import random
import time

cr = 100
print('[- play simple slot machine game -]')
time.sleep(1)
print('[- with five identical n you win -]')
time.sleep(1)
print('[- start at ' + str(cr) + 'cr place your bet -]')
time.sleep(1)
slot = []
for row in range(9):
    slot.append([None] * 9)


def print_slot(slot, empty='[ ]'):
    for row in slot:
        print(' '.join(empty if element is None else '{{: ^{}}}'.format(len(empty)).format(element) for element in row))

print_slot(slot)

time.sleep(1)
print('[- play simple slot machine game -]')
time.sleep(1)
print('[- with five identical n you win -]')
time.sleep(1)


def game_start():
    cr = 100
    bet = int(input('[- digit the num of coins to bet -] \n                 '))
    while (cr > 0) and (0 < bet <= cr):
        cr = cr - bet
        first_n = random.randint(0, 9)
        second_n = random.randint(0, 9)
        third_n = random.randint(0, 9)
        fourth_n = random.randint(0, 9)
        fifth_n = random.randint(0, 9)
        slot[4][2] = str(first_n)
        slot[4][3] = str(second_n)
        slot[4][4] = str(third_n)
        slot[4][5] = str(fourth_n)
        slot[4][6] = str(fifth_n)

        if first_n == second_n and second_n == third_n and third_n == fourth_n and fourth_n == fifth_n:
            cr += bet * 100
            time.sleep(1)
            print('[- play simple slot machine game -]')
            time.sleep(1)
            print('[- with five identical n you win -]')
            time.sleep(1)
            print_slot(slot)
            time.sleep(1)
            print('[- with five identical n you win -]')
            time.sleep(1)
            print('[- you won!!! now you have ' + str(cr) + 'cr -]')
            bet = int(input('[- digit the num of coins to bet -] \n                 '))

        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            print('[- play simple slot machine game -]')
            time.sleep(1)
            print('[- with five identical n you win -]')
            time.sleep(1)
            print_slot(slot)
            time.sleep(1)
            print('[- with five identical n you win -]')
            time.sleep(1)
            print('[-  you lose! now you have ' + str(cr) + 'cr  -]')
            bet = int(input('[- digit the num of coins to bet -] \n                 '))

    if cr <= 0:
        time.sleep(1)
        print('[- play simple slot machine game -]')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('[- with five identical n you win -]')
        time.sleep(1)
        print_slot(slot)
        time.sleep(1)
        print('[- with five identical n you win -]')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('[- you ran out of money 2 bet :( -]')

game_start()
```

Comment: i tried returning bet because without returning it pycharm keeps telling me that bet (at the top of the if statement) is not used, i guess it is the reason for need of the loop...

Comment: the `if cr <= 0` is redundant, if you are outside the loop the credit is gone, this will also break the loop if an illegal bet amount is entered even if there is credit left

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I figured you could end the game with the bet 0 while you still have credits. This should not make you feel like a loser.

Comment: I mean if you have 100 credit and you enter 101 as your first bet the game will be over where really it should relay to the user they entered an illegal amount and ask again, can't be kicking customers with money out of the casino if they make a miscalculation!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: True. There's still kinks to be worked out. But it answers the OP's principal question, "why i can't play more than one time".

Comment: Yep but it may be his/her next question! I have one condition for the loop and an if check to validate the bet. Having two together will just cause problems

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: As I said, you leave no provision for the user to leave the casino with any money left. This has to do with specification, not with implementation, and is irrelevant to the question. Can we make a better slot machine? Sure. Am I interested in spending my day to make one, given that it is not what the question is about? No.

Comment: hey, anybody interested in make a better slot? ;) i still can't replace the output in the same place instead of having the usual log (already asked, but too soon for me to apply the answer)

all my bugs corrected, can i post the complete array editing the previous one before setting the question answered?

thank you guys, merry xmas (2:29 am here)

Comment: You should not replace the code in the question with a corrected version, because any later visitors would be confused as to what the question is about. It is okay to *add* the corrected version.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are returning bet you are bringing yourself out of your entire game_start() function.  This would explain why calling game_start after returning bet wouldn't work (the program would end with the return statement!).

I think combining what you said you tried with the while loop inside the function (but after you initialize cr to 100) and removing the return statements should work.  Just change the value of bet, but don't return it.

In other words, just do what @Amadan said (was typing when he posted, and I missed the 100 - bet error)

Comment: is my `cr -= bet` ineffective? i'm combining right now with all your answers :)

Comment: Did you update your code?  I still just see cr = 100 - bet.  As @Amadan and Padraic Cunningham pointed out this will not continuously decrease cr as it should.  the recommendation of cr -= bet or equivalently cr = cr - bet should work fine.

Comment: yes i'm typing right now, step by step because i don't only want the code fixed up, i really want to understand where the error is and why.

took me 5 minutes just figure out what their little chat was about, i'm so slow with all this logic